# Get database from git project

Tags: php, git, laravel

I am a beginner in Laravel. For the purpose of studying, I downloaded and installed a [sample project from Github](https://github.com/brunogaspar/laravel-starter-kit). I followed the given steps and installed the project.

However, I don't know how to import the database from the git repository. I have searched for `.sql` files in the project folder, but none exist.

Does anyone know how to import the database of this project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to run the [migrations](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/migrations) - in Laravel, you don't import from `.sql` files, you run migrations.

```
$ php artisan migrate
```

For reference, you can find the migration files [here](https://github.com/brunogaspar/laravel-starter-kit/tree/master/app/database/migrations).

Answer (score 0):

You can use basic tools built in the mysql console.
1. Use mysqldump command, it will create a dump file of your database.
2. Add the dump file to the repository
3. If you want to install the db to a remote host, in the ssh console you can use mysql -u username dbname -p < dumpfile.dump (or .sql). You can do this on your localhost too from xampp shelp/terminal/cmd
4. Enter your password